# celery write specific log file for specific task

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, django-celery

How to write specific log file for specific task in django celery,i have write overall celery log in single log file
how to do that one

```
from redington.celery import app
from celery import shared_task


@app.task(bind=True, name='load_ibm_machine_images')
def load_ibm_machine_images(self):
    """ Task to perform To load soft-layer machine images """
    from cloudapp.management.commands.update_softlayer_machine_types import Command
    soft_layer_command_object = Command()
    soft_layer_command_object.handle()
    return True
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should dive into [django's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/) ([pythons](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html)) logging configuration

Comment: @dahrens the above is fine but i need specific task only

Comment: It is written there - create a separate logger and configure this logger to write into a file.